# How do I use modules in `spec/support/` for Ruby on Rails RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to properly use `module` files in a `spec/support/` rspec directory for a typical Ruby on Rails project.

```rb
# spec/support/page_objects/foo/bar.rb

module Foo
  module Bar  
    def hello
      "hello world"
    end
  end
end

# spec/support/page_objects/foo/foo_bar.rb

class FooBar
  include Foo::Bar
end

# spec/system/foo_bars/create_spec.rb

RSpec.describe "Create FooBar", type: :system do
  it "returns hello world"
    expect(FooBar.new.hello).to eq "hello world"
  end
end
```

I would expect `rspec spec/foo_bars/create_spec.rb` to pass, however I am receiving `uninitialized constant Foo::Bar`.

The only way I can get it working is to require the module in the class file.

```rb
# spec/support/page_objects/foo/foo_bar.rb

require_relative("bar")

class FooBar
  include Foo::Bar
end
```

Is there a way to properly use `module` files in `spec/support` to prevent having to explicitly call `require`?

Comment: There is a commented out part in  in rails_helper.rb (at least as generated by the gem) that iterates through the spec/support dir and it's subdirectories and requires all the files. Its above the RSpec.configure part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in `spec` is autoloaded by default.

Typically one adds a line to load spec/support files in spec/rails_helper.rb

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].sort.each { |f| require f }
```

Note that this will add load time to all test runs regardless of whether they use your support files. This is fine for general use support files, but not such a good idea for support files specific to a single class. Those test classes will pollute every test.

Instead, consider writing them as a [shared context](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) and including as needed. Put them in a shared_context directory. You can also load all shared contexts and examples.

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/**/shared*/*.rb')].sort.each { |f| require f }
```

---

Note that spec/support/page_objects/foo/foo_bar.rb would normally be for Foo::FooBar. FooBar should go into spec/support/page_objects/foo_bar.rb. This will have no material effect on your code, but it's good to have naming consistent with Rails standards.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions! Would `spec/support/` be an inappropriate home for `page_objects/`? I am now thinking yes as the PageObject classes are spec specific, but per the `rails_helper.rb` line, are loaded for every spec regardless of use.

Comment: @ChrisLaBarge It depends. I have a few small shared test classes in spec/support. The most important thing is be careful not to pollute the namespace. Put them in something like Fake:: or ForTesting::. I'll also write nameless classes as `let(:some_class_obj) { Class.new do ... end }` in a shared context and give them a name (if they need one) with `let(:some_class) { stub_const('SomeClass', some_class_obj) }`.